Url Launcher LaunchMode.externalApplication not working for Android Pixel API 35
Observation: Links inside the inappwebview are opening within the inappwebview and not in the external browser (Chrome) of the Android device. It is working perfectly for IOS devices, where links inside the inappwebview open only in the external browser (Safari).
Concept: In my app, users receive notifications which might have a content Url to them and certain url have redirection, therefore the idea is to first get the Final url which is responsible for checking the status code for when redirections occur, since it can go from 302 to 301 to finally 200 when redirecting. Then, the final url is passed to the inappwebview's initialUrlRequest to load the page within a inappwebview, and then for url links inside this inappwebview, they are expected to launch in the external browser when launched, but for the Android device, continue to launch within the inappwebview.
class InAppWebViewWithExternalLinkHandling extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initialUrl;

  InAppWebViewWithExternalLinkHandling({required this.initialUrl});

  @override
  _InAppWebViewWithExternalLinkHandlingState createState() => _InAppWebViewWithExternalLinkHandlingState();
}

class _InAppWebViewWithExternalLinkHandlingState extends State<InAppWebViewWithExternalLinkHandling> {
  late InAppWebViewController webViewController;
  String finalUrl = '';
  bool loading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _resolveFinalUrl(widget.initialUrl);
  }

  Future<void> _resolveFinalUrl(String initialUrl) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.head(Uri.parse(initialUrl), headers: {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"});

      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.isRedirect) {
        setState(() {
          finalUrl = response.request?.url.toString() ?? initialUrl;
          loading = false;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          finalUrl = initialUrl;
          loading = false;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        finalUrl = initialUrl;
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: loading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri(Uri.parse(finalUrl).toString())),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                webViewController = controller;
              },
              shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                final url = navigationAction.request.url.toString();
                if (navigationAction.navigationType == NavigationType.LINK_ACTIVATED) {
                  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
                    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode:LaunchMode.externalApplication);
                    return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                  }
                }
                return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}


I have found a workaround by injecting javascript code to replace the shouldOverrideUrlLoading since it was not working for Android and now any link inside the inappwebview launches to the external browser. I just have the condition for Platform.isAndroid set to the javascript implementation and Platform.isIos set to shouldOverrideUrlLoading since it works.
